# Channels with memory have higher capacity

Tags: probability, coding-theory, information-theory, entropy

I am working through Elements of Information Theory by Cover and Thomas and have come across the following solution to one of their problems that I don't understand.

Consider a binary, symmetric channel with $Y_i = X_i + Z_i$, where $+$ is mod2 addition and $X_i, Y_i \in \{0,1\}$.  Suppose that $\{Z_i\}$ has constant marginal probabilities $Pr\{Z_i=1\}=p=1-Pr\{Z_i=0\}$, but that $Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_n$ are not necessarily independent.  Assume that $Z^n$ is independent of the input $X^n$.  Let $C=1-H(p,1-p)$.  Show that $\max_{p(x_1, ..., x_n)}I(X_1,...,X_n;Y_1,...,Y_n) \ge nC$.

The solution begins by stating:

$I(X_1,...,X_n;Y_1,...,Y_n)=H(X_1,...,X_n)-H(X_1,...,X_n|Y_1,...,Y_n)=H(X_1,...,X_n)-H(Z_1,...,Z_n|Y_1,...,Y_n)$

where $X_i$ are chosen i.i.d. from Bernoulli($\frac{1}{2}$).  I don't understand how the rightmost equality is derived.  It's not an identity and is not explained.  I'm assuming that it's something simple I'm overlooking, could someone offer a hint?

Comment: Let $X,Y,Z$ be $n$-dimensional vectors.  You are given $Y=X+Z$.  So $H(X|Y) = H(Y-Z|Y) = H(-Z|Y) = H(Z|Y)$.  Overall, for any vectors $A,B$ we have $H(A+B|A)=H(B|A)$.

Comment: Oi, not enough fiddling!  Thank you!